# DIV that needs to be centered along with zooming and scrolling at the same time

Tags: html, css

In the snippet below, I have an `overflow-x: auto;` DIV containing a large table with a given width which will have a horizontal scrollbar.

There's also an Info Bar right below the table that always needs to stay centered **both on (1) zooming in/out (Ctrl+/-, larger/smaller resolutions) and (2) scrolling**.

You can see that if I go with the `position: relative` approach, the (1) Zooming keeps the bar centered, but (2) scrolling the table breaks the centering. The text string slides with the scrolling.

Alternatively, if I go with the `position: absolute` approach, the (2) Scrolling keeps the bar centerd, but (1) the Zooming breaks the centering.

I need to keep the string centered at all times both on Zooming and Scrolling. Also, the "No Results" bar can't be outside the wrapper because it can't appear below the scrollbar, it must be above it. Also, there are various tables and table widths, so the width:400px is just an example; I need some kind of dynamic solution for various widths.

```css
.tableWrapper {
   overflow-x: auto;
   width: 400px;
   height: 100px;
}

table {
   border: 1px solid black;
   font-size: 18px;
}

.infoDiv {
    /* PROBLEM:
       1) if position: relative, as right now, zooming in/out works, but scrolling breaks
       2) if position: absolute, scrolling works, but zooming in/out breaks
    */
    
    /* position: relative option */
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.infoDiv2 {
    /* position: absolute option */
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
}
```

```html
APPROACH 1
<div class="tableWrapper">
   <table class="table">
      <thead>
         <th>Column 1</th>
         <th>Column 2</th>
         <th>Column 3</th>
         <th>Column 4</th>
         <th>Column 5</th>
         <th>Column 6</th>
         <th>Column 7</th>
         <th>Column 8</th>
         <th>Column 9</th>
         <th>Column 10</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   
   <div class="infoDiv">
      No Results Found
   </div>
</div>

APPROACH 2
<div class="tableWrapper">
   <table class="table">
      <thead>
         <th>Column 1</th>
         <th>Column 2</th>
         <th>Column 3</th>
         <th>Column 4</th>
         <th>Column 5</th>
         <th>Column 6</th>
         <th>Column 7</th>
         <th>Column 8</th>
         <th>Column 9</th>
         <th>Column 10</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   
   <div class="infoDiv2">
      No Results Found
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean No Results Found should stick to the center of viewable area and not moving with scrolling? What do you mean by zooming?

Comment: Yes. By zooming I mean, if you press Ctrl+/- to enlarge the screen.

Comment: You could argue if the `.infoDiv` should even be within the `.tableWrapper`. If it's not in there, then it won't be part of the scrolling and will stay in its place.

Comment: The reason it needs to be part of the scrolling is that "No Results" cannot appear below the table's scrollbar. It must appear above any table scrollbar, as part of the table information.

Comment: With position absolute it will not move if you change the left value to fixed i.e 100px, is that what you want?

Comment: Actually, yes, you're right! I just updated the OP to be a fixed 'px' value and it does work on zooming -- but i have different table widths.

Comment: @Stickers So I can't guarantee a specific table width; i have multiple tables I need to apply this solution to dynamically.

Comment: Also, resizing the window will break that `absolute` px value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `position: sticky`

> The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the document, and then offset relative to its nearest scrolling ancestor and containing block (nearest block-level ancestor). [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?v=example#sticky)

```
.infoDiv2 {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```css
.tableWrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.infoDiv2 {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

body {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tableWrapper">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
      <th>Column 6</th>
      <th>Column 7</th>
      <th>Column 8</th>
      <th>Column 9</th>
      <th>Column 10</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div class="infoDiv2">
    No Results Found
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup! This seems to be the right solution. Works on scrolling, resizing, and zooming. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```css
.tableWrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.infoDiv {
  /* position: relative option */
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="tableWrapper">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
      <th>Column 4</th>
      <th>Column 5</th>
      <th>Column 6</th>
      <th>Column 7</th>
      <th>Column 8</th>
      <th>Column 9</th>
      <th>Column 10</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div class="infoDiv">
    No Results Found
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work, you can see in the snippet that if I scroll the string loses its position and isn't centered.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your desired outcome but check my latest edit

Comment: Thanks, looks good; but do you need to give a `width` to the DIV? I don't know the width of the table in advance.

Comment: Welcome, and I re-edited to set the text to inherit the wrapper's width, now it should work and the text will take whatever the wrapper width

Comment: Thanks good solution but I guess the `position:sticky` answer below is even better. Appreciate it